# How does this circuit work? (24 V lead-acid charger)

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, lead-acid

How should this circuit be controlled to ensure that the backup battery is properly charged? The battery is a 24 V lead-acid battery.

This is a circuit diagram of a UPS device.

A PWM signal is connected to the R15 resistor (I checked with an oscilloscope) that monitors the battery charge.
As I understand it, the battery is charged to about 26 V and then the PWM signal is turned on and off every 100 ms. The duty cycle is about 23%.

Is this method correct?

The battery is used less than 10 times during the day, up to 30 seconds, up to 15 A.

I do not understand the constant voltage charging step in this circuit. I think in this circuit the battery is constantly charging. Is this true?

[image]

Comment: A source of info on lead-acid is the [battery university](https://batteryuniversity.com/articles).

Comment: Are you considering making your own charger? It's not clear. But if so, then you should examine the relevant research materials. You'll find that pulsed current charging, 1 second on and 3 seconds off, is about optimal during the "constant current" charging phase (the 1st phase.) This may explain the 23% figure you are finding, though it does not explain the 100 ms cycle period. Either way, I believe it should only apply in the case of the 1st charging phase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simulate the circuit below to get a feel for how it works :)

D31 protects Q11 from reverse breakdown. Q11 is a PWM driver with current limiting (about 1A) established by Q10+R8.

MCU_ADC samples battery voltage scaled-down by R14+R17 divider.

When Q12 is turned on, Q11 can conduct, otherwise it's cut off. R12 drains the base charge from Q11 on turn-off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH5Mmv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can easily observe, this circuit will not develop full current control via Q10 unless Q11 is a Darlington type. In the circuit you're copying, hopefully Q11 is a Darlington, or else someone snafu-ed the design a bit.

Supposed that Q11 is not a Darlington, but just a medium-power PNP device with beta of, let's say 30 at IC=1A, the base would need to be driven with 33mA. Yet, 44V/10kOhm(R13)=4.4mA. That won't be enough to turn most non-Darlington devices on. Thus, R13 is likely too large.

I'd decrease R13 to 1kOhm, and configure Q12 as a constant current sink turned on/off by the MCU. The newly added R100 would set the base current of Q11, large enough to ensure that Q11 can deliver the full charge current of about 1.4A even if it has minimum beta (per datasheet).

In this case, R15 and R16 have to be changed as well. R15 needs to be 4k7, and R16 is a 100kOhm pull-down to keep Q12 off when the MCU is initializing and its PWM pin is open-circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNoZCd.png)</sup>

When the battery is discharged to, say 20V, Q11 will be dissipating about 20-35W at the beginning of charge. It needs to be rated to dissipate 50W-75W at least, and must have a suitable heatsink. The extra factor of safety is needed not to exceed Q11's safe operating area (SOA): after all, it's running with a rather large collector-emitter voltage of 20-25V, depending on the state of charge of the battery.

To protect Q11 from damage when the battery is discharged too deeply, the MCU should do roughly as follows:

1. When the battery voltage is between 0-20V, run the PWM at 1%-100%, proportionally. This will limit dissipation on Q11.
2. When the battery voltage is between 20-26V, keep PWM at 100% (constant on).
3. When the battery voltage reaches 26V for the first time, switch to the stand-by charging mode - below.
4. Check the battery voltage every 100ms, and if it's below 26V, issue a single 100ms pulse, turn PWM off, wait 100ms, go to 4.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . that was perfect.
In the main circuit, between 20 and 26 volts, the PWM signal is connected for 15 seconds, then disconnected, the voltage is measured, and then the signal reconnected. When the voltage reaches 26 volts, the signal is switched on and off continuously every 100 milliseconds. Doesn't this repetition every 100 milliseconds cause a problem?

Comment: Generally, lead-acid chargers must have both CV and CC control. The MCU plays the role of a CV controller, with higher voltage pulses that aid in desulfation. As long as the MCU does not do any charging when the voltage on the battery is over it’s fully-charged limit, things should be OK. If you trust your MCU, that is. Otherwise a bug or a hang can cause the battery to overcharge and vent. A minor modification to this circuit could add pulsed CV control where the MCU would only have a supervisory instead of a control role.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a good design of a pulse float charger with CV and current limiter R8 = 0.7 V/0.5 ohm = 1.4 A using base clamp with Q10. (Standard BJT current limiter.)

As the battery has very large  C and low ESR relative to the current dV/dt=Ic/C will produce low ripple until the battery ages with high ESR.

The software algorithm for PWM and voltage error from 26V reference for SLA batteries seems suitable.  Pulse charging is a better approach as it also desulfanates to maintain ESR to some extent rather than over voltage as done in open lead acid cells.

23% duty cycle at 10 Hz of 1.4A max is 0.32 A or 8.3W of power. It depends the actual current is limited or less than this but probing the current sense 0.5 ohm resistor drop with 2 probes will verify my assumption.

Charge efficiency is about 70% for Ah out/in when new. If this drops significantly it might indicate a single cell failure with ~ 2V / cell meaning you might have a 22V battery with low capacity instead of a 24V battery.  Capacity is limited by the weakest cell in series.

Removing the charger and plotting the Ah consumed and compare with rating will be the best way to determine condition of battery without a tester.  But 24% steady standby charge with no load seems a little high for a good battery. I would expect < 5%. at 26/24V ratio.

### opinion

The 15A load will drop the battery voltage with 15-1.4A supplied by the battery to the  load. Vdrop ought to be < 5%.

Measuring the Vbat voltage drop will indicate the ESR of Vbat and this correlates well with aging inversely with Wh rating of batteries. e.g. 24V 10Ah or 240 Wh should have an ESR <= 0.1 ohm meaning 13.6A load should drop << 1.36 V.  before end of life and much less when new.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please provide a source for reading or, if so, what should I search for?

Comment: Is there a problem if the battery is constantly charging?

Comment: @macrobert The 23% duty cycle you see may be based upon the battery self-discharge, itself. I tend to assume that when there is an MCU involved like this, that there is software in there doing something other than "nothing at all." So it should be taking readings and adjusting the duty cycle based upon observation. I don't think the MCU just drives it 23% all the time. What's the point in having an MCU, if so? Seems silly. Could have just used a simple timer circuit or a 555 and be done with it if the MCU doesn't do anything intelligent. Is this your only question? Or is there something else?

Comment: " 10 times during the day, up to 30 seconds, up to 15 A"  if 10Ah and used every 2hr for 30s or 15/(2*60) = 0.125 Ah, it should be fully charged within 1h with low idle charge for a uC.

Comment: What % is your V drop at 15A?

Comment: @jonk The microcontroller is also responsible for other tasks. But in the case of the battery, it adjusts the pulse duration in several steps.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks for the explanation. I did not measure the voltage drop. I learned good points from you.

Comment: @macrobert You may want to read, *"Recovery of discarded sulfated lead-acid batteries,"* Karami, H., & Asadi, R. (2009), Journal of Power Sources, 191(1), 165–175. doi: 10.1016/j.jpowsour.2008.12.153

Comment: that's @jonk no joke , here is the article https://www.ijsr.net/archive/v6i10/ART20177089.pdf#:~:text=Therefore%2C%20there%20is%20a%20general%20need%20in%20the,and%20Artificial%20Intelligent%20%5B33-38%5D%2C%20Other%20Techniques%20%5B39-40%5D%20etc.  I can validate the results are positive if performed within a few months of  sulfation. I and others have performed SEM and specific gravity tests to validate the effects of pulse charging  but I doubt 1 Hz will have any effective energy at piezoeletric resonant frequencies.it needs to be much higher f.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  , oh sorry . Thank you both